# On ngOnOnit, input data of a child component are already there?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component that makes two separate calls to service and gets a list A and a list B. Then it passes those two lists as Input parameters to the child component. In child component, when ngOnInit executes, should I take for granted, that both lists are already there and I can move on with some comparisons or the lists can "arrive" at different moments?

For example, if list A is already there (on child) but list B is pending and undefined, the comparison will make a wrong result.